# How do I keep track of groupings certain elements are part of?

Tags: regex, perl

I apologize for the shoddy title; I have no idea how to properly describe the issue I am having.

I have multiple tab-delimited files in the following format:

```
groupA    donuts     apples
groupB    car        dog        ball      meter
groupC    apples     donuts     car
groupD    ball       shirt      pencil    paper      donuts
```

with differing number of rows.

For each line, the first word is the group name while the rest of line are names of objects.
What I want to do is keep track of what groups each object is part of.
So in this example, I would find that `ball` is part of `groupD` and `groupB` while `car` is only part of `groupC`. `apples` is part of `groupA` and `groupC` while `pencil` is only part of `groupD`.

Since each file I'm reading in has differing number of rows/groups, what is the best way to go about accomplishing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = "../GENELIST.symbols.csv";
open(PATH, $path) || die "cannot open csv\n";
my @groups = ();
while(my $line = <PATH>){
    if($line =~ /^(\w+)\t/){
        push(@groups, $1);
    }
}
close(PATH);
#at this point I have the name of all the groups in the particular file (`groupA`, `groupB`, `groupC`, `groupD`).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a hash of arrays.

To get more familiar with such structures, check out: [`Perl Data Structures Cookbook`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %groups;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($group, @cols) = split;
    push @{$groups{$_}}, $group for @cols;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%groups;

__DATA__
groupA    donuts     apples
groupB    car        dog        ball      meter
groupC    apples     donuts     car
groupD    ball       shirt      pencil    paper      donuts
```

Outputs:

```
{
  apples => ["groupA", "groupC"],
  ball   => ["groupB", "groupD"],
  car    => ["groupB", "groupC"],
  dog    => ["groupB"],
  donuts => ["groupA", "groupC", "groupD"],
  meter  => ["groupB"],
  paper  => ["groupD"],
  pencil => ["groupD"],
  shirt  => ["groupD"],
}
```

Comment: What a model of concise!